# Asp.net core Razor pages - foreach loop for a collection of parameters

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to display results of a query that runs for multiple parameters.

I am passing parameters to OnGet with

```
public IActionResult OnPostEvaluareA(string ea, string[] ecs, string ezl)
        {

            return RedirectToPage("/RO/Pages/evaris/Index", new { ea, ezl, ecs });

        }
```

Then the parameters are used in a query that gets data from tables for all parameters with

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string ea, string ezl, string[] ecs, string emlm, int count)
{
if(ecs != null)
            {
                foreach(var item in ecs)
                {
                    EvarisListCS = await (from a in _context.EvarisCaracterSpecials.Where(s => s.OrgID == orgid && s.ECS == item)
                                        join b in _context.EvarisMains on a.ECS equals b.ECS into Temp1
                                        from c in Temp1
                                        join d in _context.EvarisMasuras on c.EMID equals d.EMID into Temp2
                                        from e in Temp2
                                        select new EvarisMasuraList
                                        {
                                            ID = a.ECS,
                                            Pericol = c.Pericol,
                                            FormaManifestare = c.FormaManifestare,
                                            RiscInitial = c.Risc,
                                            Clasa = e.Clasa,
                                            Masura = e.Masura,
                                            RiscFinal = e.RiscFinal
                                        }).ToListAsync();

                    if (EvarisListCS.Count > 0)
                    {
                        HaveListCS = true;
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

And the results are displayed with an foreach loop as well

```
@if (Model.HaveListCS == true)
{
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label class="form-control text-center" style="background-color:dodgerblue; color:whitesmoke">Pericol</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label class="form-control text-center" style="background-color:dodgerblue; color:whitesmoke">Forma de manifestare</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <label class="form-control text-center" style="background-color:dodgerblue; color:whitesmoke">Risc initial</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <label class="form-control text-center" style="background-color:dodgerblue; color:whitesmoke">Clasa</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <label class="form-control text-center" style="background-color:dodgerblue; color:whitesmoke">Masura</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-1">
            <label class="form-control text-center" style="background-color:dodgerblue; color:whitesmoke">Risc final</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    @foreach (var group in Model.EvarisListCS.GroupBy(s => s.ID))
    {
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <span class="form-control" style="font-size: 18px; background-color: antiquewhite; font-weight: 600">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => group.Key)</span>
        </div>
        foreach (var item in group)
        {
            <div class="row no-gutters mb-2">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <textarea rows="2" class="form-control text-center" style="font-size: 12px; resize: none; ">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Pericol)</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <textarea rows="2" class="form-control text-center" style="font-size: 12px; resize: none; ">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.FormaManifestare)</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <textarea rows="2" class="form-control text-center" style="font-size: 12px; resize: none; ">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.RiscInitial)</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <textarea rows="2" class="form-control text-center" style="font-size: 12px; resize: none; ">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Clasa)</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <textarea rows="2" class="form-control text-center" style="font-size: 12px; resize: none; ">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Masura)</textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-1">
                    <textarea rows="2" class="form-control text-center" style="font-size: 12px; resize: none; ">@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.RiscFinal)</textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that de results contains data from query for only one parameter while I send 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could pass the parameters in the query part

```
?ecs[0]=xxx&ecs[1]=xxxx
```

or

```
?ecs=xxx&ecs=xxxx
```

in PageModel:

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet =true)]
        public string[] ecs { get; set; }
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

**Update**:

EvarisListCS would be assigned with a new value in each loop, So results contains data from query for only last parameter

It seems you defined your property :

```
public IList<EvarisMasuraList> EvarisListCS {get;set;}
```

You Could Create a new instance of List

```
var newlist=new List<EvarisMasuraList>();
//in Loop
newlist.AddRange();

// out of loop
EvarisListCS=newlist;
```

Comment: Parameters are passed to OnGet with  `public IActionResult OnPostEvaluareA(string ea, string[] ecs, string ezl)
        {

            return RedirectToPage("/RO/Pages/evaris/Index", new { ea, ezl, ecs });

        }`. I do get the parameters but I can run the query for all of them

Comment: So what's your problem now?

Comment: The query only runs for a single parameter.

Comment: I've updated the question with more details

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check it

Comment: for the first solution I get the following error on load ` InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<EvarisCaracterSpecial>
.Where(e => e.OrgID == __orgid_0 && Array.IndexOf<string>(
array: __ecs_1,
value: e.ECS) != -1)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). `

Comment: for the second solution, I've tried it before but was not working. Error `'IList<EvarisMasuraList>' does not contain a definition for 'AddRange' and no accessible extension method 'AddRange' accepting a first argument of type 'IList<EvarisMasuraList>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
`

Comment: I've updated my answer.please check it

Comment: you are right, the property is declared as mentioned. I modified the code to reflect your solution and newlist.AddRange(evaris); where evaris is the query but I still get results for only one parameter. `Where(s => s.OrgID == orgid && s.ECS == item)` and foreach loop in place.

Comment: Have you tried to move EvarisListCS=newlist; outof loop?

Comment: I had to change evaris (it was also name of the namespace) to results, took it out of the loop (including list declaration) and.....The name 'results' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Ok it worked. I took List declaration outside of loop before the foreach, I left newlist.AddRange(results); inside the loop and I took EvarisListCS = newlist; outside the loop as well, after the foreach and is working. Thank you very much. Please update your answer so I can mark it.